# trying to create an array of struct pointer but get heap/buffer/etc violation statistically

Tags: c, visual-studio

i have two structs

```
typedef enum { False = 0, True = 1 } bool;
//defenition of candy structure
typedef struct _Candy {
    char candy_name[16];
    bool vegan;
}Candy;
typedef struct _Child {
    char child_name[16];
    Candy *candy_of_child;
}Child;
```

now im trying to create an array of pointers that each one is Child type
[*Child,*Child...] etc
now i can initialize it i need to do it dynamically

the function that does in is:

```
int AllocateKidsArray(int NumOfKids, Child** ptr_to_child_arr) {
//=================================================
//"AllocateKidsArray" intializing an array of childrens
//Input:  1. int indicating the number of kids
//        2. pointer to an array of children
//Output: 1. return an int value {0}->Success {-1}->Failure
//        2. pointer to an empty initialized array of childerns
//=================================================
// array of length NumOfKids, consisting of Child pointers
Child **ptr_to_childs = malloc(NumOfKids * sizeof(Child*));
int i;
for (i = 0; i < NumOfKids; i++) {
    ptr_to_childs[i] = malloc(sizeof(Child));
    strncpy((*ptr_to_childs[i]).child_name, "", 16);
    (*ptr_to_childs)[i].candy_of_child = NULL;
}
*ptr_to_child_arr = *ptr_to_childs;
//for (i = 0; i < NumOfKids; i++) {
//  free(ptr_to_childs[i]);
//}
//free(ptr_to_childs);
return 0;
}
```

im calling it from the main in the following manner:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
//=================================================
if (argc < 3) {
    printf("Incorrect number of arguments. Please invoke the program \n\t./program.exe < input.txt> <output.txt> \n");
    exit(1);
}
int i, lines, checker = 0;
Candy *test = NULL;
char* name_test = NULL;
char* candy_test = NULL;
char* line = "Tamar,Apple\n";
int* NumLinesFile = NULL;
Child *ArrayOfChild = NULL;
.
.
.
//GetNumLines check
printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
printf("%s\n", argv[2]);
GetNumLines(argv[1], &NumLinesFile);
lines = *NumLinesFile;
*NumLinesFile = NULL;
printf("%d\n", lines);
//=================================================
//AllocateKidsArray check
//AllocateKidsArray(lines, &ArrayOfChild);
AllocateKidsArray(lines, &ArrayOfChild);
//ImportKidsArray check
ImportKidsArray(argv[1], lines, &ArrayOfChild);
for (i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    //ArrayOfChild[i].candy_of_child = (Candy*) malloc(sizeof(Candy*));
    printf("%s,%s\n", ArrayOfChild[i].child_name, ArrayOfChild[i].candy_of_child->candy_name);
}
//=================================================
```

and im statistically get heap/buffer violation
i suspect this function but i dont know what is wrong with it.

after the init of the array i pass it to another function that fills it in:

```
int ImportKidsArray(char* file_addr, int num_kids, Child** array_of_kids_to_fill) {
//=================================================
//"ImportKidsArray" reads the file and assign each valid line to cell in the array
//Input:  1. string to a location of a file
//        2. int indicating the number of kids
//        3. pointer to an array of children
//Output: 1. return an int value {0}->Success {-1}->Failure
//        2. pointer to an initialized array of childerns
//=================================================
FILE *fp;
char character;
char line[32];
int i = 0, j = 1, checker = 0, arr_count = 0;
char* TempChild = NULL;
char* TempCandy = NULL;
Child *arr = *array_of_kids_to_fill;

fp = fopen(file_addr, "r");
// Check if file exists
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Could not open file %s", file_addr);
    return -1;
}
while (!feof(fp)) {
    fgets(line, 32, fp);
    checker = ParseLine(line, &TempChild, &TempCandy);
    GetCandy(TempCandy, &(arr[arr_count].candy_of_child));
    strncpy((arr[arr_count]).child_name, TempChild, 16);
    arr_count++;

}
return 0;
}
```

please if anyone can help, it will save my life :)

Comment: The first thing I've noticed is that you're allocating the size of a child pointer instead of the size of a child...

Comment: Do you need to use raw arrays and this stuff? C++ has very nice things that abstract those? And unless all those Kids will go out and kill you for not giving them candy, it is probably only a bad score.

Comment: what do you mean in raw arrays?

Comment: @chemist.: Post the content of those files..(input file and output file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change to `ArrayOfChild`. Passing it's address from `main()`.

Change it by appropriately de-referencing it.

```
*ptr_to_childs = malloc(NumOfKids * sizeof(Child));
```

Then do rest of the operation on `*ptr_to_childs`. That will retain the change that you made in the called function.

Also check the return value of `malloc`. And free(using `free()`) the memory dynamically allocated.

If you notice carefully you will see in the `ArrayOfChild()` function you are working with a local variable `Child **ptr_to_childs`. You certainly don't want that as that variable will not be alive when the function ends.

Also `while (!feof(fp))` is not appropriate to use. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) link for that.

Another thing is check the return value of `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)`.

> On success, the function returns the same `str` parameter. If the
>   End-of-File is encountered and no characters have been read, the
>   contents of `str` remain unchanged and a NULL is returned.

Comment: where sholud i use free?
in the allocatearray function or should i call a new function which will get the array that i work with inside the main and free evrey cell of it?

Comment: @chemist.: For example when you have processed this dynamicaly allocated memory or simply you dont need them at a point- call `free()` on them.

Comment: i see, and do i need to call only one free on the main pointer to the array, or should i go over every cell in the array?

Comment: @chemist.: Yes whatever you allocate...you need to `free()` it. The variable which contains the mallcoaed address call free() on it.